# Modern opengl rendering pipeline

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glfw, glew

Okay i have been studying opengl online, however most tutorials i have been seeing only cover the fixed pipeline. I am trying to add it into an object oriented project, however i am not quiet sure the modern process with shaders and such. Is the process as easy as binding a buffer, as well as a shader? And what exactly are handles used for? I have added glew and glfw, even though now my log is saying glew failed to initialize, error 1282, thats a whole different topic, unless glew and glfw are incompatable. Can anyone shine a light on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handles in opengl are just `GLInt`s, which for example could be used to work with a VBO, VAO, stuff like that.

As for the shader, it uses the glsl shading language. Then they give the functions to compile and link the shader to your opengl context.

Asking how shaders, handles, and setting up the environment work for opengl is a very broad question, you would be better off following a tutorial. A good one would be [OpenglDev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html) which covers all the basic concepts, as well as some advanced ones. It's not opengl-es, but if you understand those tutorials opengl-es should be no problem transitioning to. The Visual Studio solution project is available for download [Here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/ogldev-source.zip), which will come with the project already setup with the required libraries.